# Post data in javascript using ajax and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/j.json",
        data: {
            "employees": [{
                "firstName": "Peter",
                    "lastName": "Jones"
            }]
        },
        success: function () {
            alert("Data Sent");
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Status: " + textStatus);
            alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

Getting Error. Error handler is showing
status: parsererror
and then
Error: SyntaxError:Unexpected end of input

Comment: I would not recommend using the keyword XMLHttpRequest as a parameter name.

Comment: @GrantTimmerman, `XMLHttpRequest` is not a keyword. `while` is a keyword. `XMLHttpRequest` is a function's name.

Comment: That error would seem to indicate that the Ajax call itself _worked_ but then the result came back in a format that couldn't be parsed. Possibly you aren't returning valid JSON, or given that you don't set `dataType:'json'` jQuery may be trying to interpret the response as something else - does your `http://localhost/j.json` page set the MIME type of the response properly?

Comment: i agree, please check the response your server sent back in the error console of your browser.

Comment: Not working.Or just comment me working code to post data to json file on same computer

Comment: Not working? Try harder. Though it doesn't make sense to "post data to json file". Does the server-side part of this transaction appear to be working? If so, given you don't seem to be using the response in your success function if you just want to sweep the dust under the carpet you could perhaps set `dataType:'text'` so that jQuery doesn't try to parse the result and then you won't get a parse error. Or you could use `dataType:'text'` in combination with a `console.log()` to see what the response actually contains...

Comment: `"employees": [{
                "firstName": "Peter",
                    "lastName": "Jones"
            }]` is not a string. make it as a string and then try

Comment: @nnnnnn now giving me Data sent but nothing is in j.json file